# Blueimp - Not able to view uploaded files in IE

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

When I upload a file using the default settings for the blueimp jQuery File Upload on my webserver, I'm unable to view the files in Internet Explorer 11. The upload completes successfully from IE however once the upload completes, the space with the filename/start/cancel disappears and appears as though no files exist. When I open the page in Chrome and Firefox, I can see all of the files including the new one uploaded in IE.  I'm using the Basic Plus UI.

I get the same results using the demo site from github https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried checking the javascript console for error in IE 11

Comment: It's saying 'A security problem occurred' File: jquery.min.js, Line: 4, Column: 12459
The jquery file points to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js.  Does IE not like calling remote files?  Should I move everything local?

Comment: Nothing like that, can we see some of your code , specially the js files inclusion part , and I will be in a better position to comment